# PostgreSQL/TimescaleDB: How to save only rows with a delta relative to the last similar row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, timescaledb

I've got a table storing rows of the general form `(time, value1, value2, value3)`, where each `value` often remains the same over a long period of time (but the two do not necessarily change simultaneously). I don't want to waste space on storing many rows of no change.

I've seen [TimescaleDB query to select rows where column value changed from previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331247/timescaledb-query-to-select-rows-where-column-value-changed-from-previous-row), but that relies on a window function where the table as a whole already contains all the no-change rows. Wouldn't it be better to have a table constraint of some kind so that the insertion can simply `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`?

I had also considered the structure `(time, kind, value)`, for the possibility that this would make it easier to write the constraint requested, since there wouldn't be the need to handle the case of "only one of the values changes", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main goal is to save space, I'd just benchmark your space overhead storing the raw data and make sure you enable compression.  If you have long runs of identical values, run-length encoding should compress that *really* well.

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression

I realize only a partial answer, but thought I'd offer that observation.

(TImescaleDB person here)